# Open phpMyadmin from another computer

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

This is not really a programming question.
I'm trying to open phpMyAdmin hosted by MAMPPro on another computer (in the same network). I goto web browser and type

```
http://<IP Address>/phpmyadmin/
```

but I get unauthorized message. Can someone tell me which setting should I change to access phpmyadmin on another computer. It opens on the same computer.

Thanks

Comment: Might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921575/access-phpmyadmin-over-lan-using-mamp